# "this" reference changing when passing it as parameter with RMI

Tags: java, reference, rmi

I am struggling with a problem. I have client & a server program, and I use RMI to communicate between them.

The method "connect" is invoked client-side and the client pass its own reference as parameter `stub.connect(this)`

In the `connect(this)` method, the server puts `this` (client reference) in a List and a HashMap. I have checked that they are both populated.

The problem is that when I want to find the reference in the Map or the List later it seems like `this` have changed. As example, I call `move(this,direction)` from client, the server does not find the associated client in both map & hashmap.

Here is the `stub.connect(this)` call code :

```
    public class Client extends JFrame implements KeyListener, IClient{

        private IServer stub;
        private Grid gameGrid;

        public Client() throws AccessException, RemoteException, NotBoundException{
            gameGrid = new Grid();
            setTitle("Sweet collector game");
            setSize(840, 560);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            add(gameGrid);
            setVisible(true);
            addKeyListener(this);

            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(10000);
            stub = (IServer) registry.lookup("IServer");
            stub.connect(this);
       }
```

Server side connect method :

```
public void connect(IClient c) throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("New player joined the game !");
    this.currentPlayers.add(c);
    Random rand = new Random();
    Position2D<Integer,Integer> init = new Position2D<Integer,Integer>(rand.nextInt(gridsize-1),rand.nextInt(gridsize-1));
    while(this.sweetsPosition.contains(init) || this.playersPosition.containsValue(init)){
        init = new Position2D<Integer,Integer>(rand.nextInt(gridsize-1),rand.nextInt(gridsize-1));
    }
    this.playersPosition.put(c,init);
}
```

But when I call `move(this,direction)` from same client it cant find the right object in list/map :

```
public void move(int direction, IClient c) throws RemoteException {
        if(this.playersPosition.containsKey(c)){ //always return FALSE for a reason I ignore
```

The call from (obviously, same) client :

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
    int keyCode = k.getKeyCode();
    try {
        stub.move(keyCode, this);
```

I hope I exposed my issue enough. I really need your help, i do not think I can fix this alone... Maybe it is not even related to RMI.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might want to consider an ID system of sorts. It'll make finding the client easier as the ID SHOULDN'T change.

Comment: I would like a better solution, I should be able to pass object via RMI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you pass an `IClient` via RMI  the receiver will receive a different object. Unless `IClient` implements `equals()` and `hashCode()` correctly, it therefore won't work as a hashmap key.

You should also *not* be passing around JFrames via Serialization. See the Javadoc for a major warning, and in any case it doesn't make sense. Refactor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, then I should implements "equals" & "hashcode" to identify my clients onto my server ? And put the JFrame as an attribute. Thanks again

Comment: As a `transient` attribute.